# nginx / FastCGI application loads page multiple times per request

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

I was following [this tutorial](http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/), and I modified the code slightly and added a counter to it. The page displays "Hello World" and then displays the counter. Now, the weird thing is, the code compiles fine, but the count goes up by 2 each time I refresh the page!

I'm spawning the process like this: `spawnfcgi.exe -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -f myapp.exe`

Everything loads OK, but again, the count jumps from 0 to 2 to 4 etc. each time I refresh the page. If I were to write a line to a file, the same line would be written multiple times, increasing each time I load the webpage. My question is, is this the intended effect of a FastCGI application? Or is there some kind of bug in my code and/or FastCGI/nginx config?

#### main.cpp (Hello World)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fcgio.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
     int gcount = 0;

     // Backup the stdio streambufs
     streambuf * cin_streambuf  = cin.rdbuf();
     streambuf * cout_streambuf = cout.rdbuf();
     streambuf * cerr_streambuf = cerr.rdbuf();

     FCGX_Request request;

     FCGX_Init();
     FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

     while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)
     {
         fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
         fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
         fcgi_streambuf cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);

         cin.rdbuf(&cin_fcgi_streambuf);
         cout.rdbuf(&cout_fcgi_streambuf);
         cerr.rdbuf(&cerr_fcgi_streambuf);

         cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
         << "\r\n"
         << "<html>\n"
         << "  <head>\n"
         << "    <title>Hello, World!</title>\n"
         << "  </head>\n"
         << "  <body>\n"
         << "    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>\n"
         << gcount++
         << "  </body>\n"
         << "</html>\n";

         // Note: the fcgi_streambuf destructor will auto flush
     }

     // restore stdio streambufs
     cin.rdbuf(cin_streambuf);
     cout.rdbuf(cout_streambuf);
     cerr.rdbuf(cerr_streambuf);

     return 0;
}
```

#### nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8000;

      fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
      fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```

#### fastcgi.conf

```
#fastcgi.conf
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your nginx.conf ?

And is your browser chrome or something like chronium?

Comment: Posted nginx.conf and fastcgi.conf. I'm using Google Chrome. Thanks

Comment: Oh, Chrome will send a request "/favicon.ico" to get the site LOGO, which you can find it in the nginx access logs. Therefore, every time you refresh the page, 2 requests are sent actually.

Comment: I tried it with firefox, and you're right. Thanks again for your guidance. When chrome requests /favicon.ico, is there a way to stream/send the favicon back, or does fastcgi do that automatically? I added a favicon.ico to the html/ folder, and I still can't see my favicon.

Comment: Fastcgi doesn't care what the request is. If only the location is matched, fastcgi processes it. That's not enough to add a favicon.ico in html folder. You should also add a location section: /favicon.ico in nginx.conf to tell nginx respond what the request need. Make sure the favicon.ico can be READ by nginx. Good luck.